# R: error in write_pzfx : These tables are not all numeric:

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export

I want to export a table of data frames from R to a .pzfx file for Graphpad Prism. For that, I have found a function called `write_pzfx` from the package 'pzfx', which in principle seems like my solution.

Yet when I try to export it, I get the following error

> Error in write_pzfx(list_export, :
>   These tables are not all numeric:

And "these tables" are all the dataframes within the list.

As far as I was concerned, this function allowed data frames to be exported, as it is said in the link (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pzfx/vignettes/pzfx.html):

> There is a write_pzfx function for writing. It takes as input a data frame or a matrix, or a named list of data frames or matrices, and writes to a `.pzfx` file.

The data I'm trying to export is the following:

A list of 80 elements. Each element is a class `data.frame`, with its first column being a factor (which will later become the X column) and the rest being numeric vectors with some NAs.

I would like to preserve this structure, as the .pzfx output should be like that: 80 sheets which correspond with the 80 dataframes in the list.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Okay nevermind, I found a solution. If anyone's interested: I deleted the first column (factor) and kept all the dataframes as matrixes instead, using that first column as rownames and using the argument `row_names = TRUE` in the function `write_pzfx`. Should I delete the question or leave it so that other people who might have the same problem can see it?